# Calling method on a struct that implements a protocol

Tags: swift

**UPDATE START**
It was because this array was coming from Objective-C and there were some screw-ups happening in the whole process. Needed some fixes, but all the answers below are correct. 
**UPDATE END**

I've a protocol as below

```
protocol SomeProtocol
{
    func someFunctionProtocol
}
```

There is a struct that implements this protocol as

```
struct SomeStruct: SomeProtocol
{
   ....
}
```

Now, at runtime, I get an argument `arg: Any` that I know for sure will implement `SomeProtocol`

How should I call this protocol method on `arg`. I have tried
`let ob = arg as! HanselProviderProtocol`, however this gives me runtime error `Could not cast value of type '_SwiftValue' (0x111952720) to 'SomeProtocol' (0x111957158)`

The images below show that it is not working

[image: Struct Defn]

=====
[image: Debug]

Comment: Offtopic: Don't us `!` in Swift code. Use `guard` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While I will take care of it - will it also solve the runtime crash and call the method implemented by `SomeStruct`. It may solve the runtime crash, but would end up not calling the method.

Comment: @prabodhprakash provide more exapanded example

Comment: Im not sure. Please try `guard let ob = arg as? SomeProtocol`. But I'm not sure you can cast to a protocol type. Try casting to a struct type.

Comment: It does not work. gets into `else` condition of `guard`

Comment: Which Swift version are you using?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you were to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift3, you can cast the argument of type `Any` to a protocol:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func someFunctionProtocol()
}

struct SomeStruct: SomeProtocol {
    func someFunctionProtocol() {
        print("Yep")
    }
}

func test(arg: Any) {
    if let castee = arg as? SomeProtocol {
        castee.someFunctionProtocol()
    }
}

test(arg: SomeStruct())
```

Prints:

```
Yep
```

Comment: Works fine for me standalone - but somehow fails in my code ! - Let me see if I am making some mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Type cast the `Any` type to the `struct` type, not the `protocol`.

```
guard let ob = arg as? SomeStruct else { 
 print("invalid type")
 return 
}

ob.someFunctionProtocol()
```

**EDIT**

Or just check with the `is` keyword.

```
 let foo: Any = SomeStruct()

 if foo is SomeProtocol {
   // you can safely use force unwrapping here, because the condition above returned true
   (foo as! SomeProtocol).someFunctionProtocol()
 }
```

If you would be using SwiftLint, you can disable the force cast warning or error with the following command:

```
// swiftlint:disable:this force_cast
```

Comment: I cannot cast it to `SomeStruct` as there may be more than this `struct` that implements the protocol and come in `arg`

Comment: than just check with the `is` keyword. updated my answer.

Comment: The problem with not casting it is that you can not call the Protocols functions. ´arg.someFunctionOfProtocol()` will not compile, even you know it `is SomeProtocol`.

Comment: well, just force cast the variable to the protocol. updated my answer.

Comment: force casting can break your build when you are using swiftlint for example.

Comment: @AndreyGershengoren than add the `// swiftlint:disable:this force_cast` after the force cast. I do not understand, what is all this hate for force casting. Of course, do not be crazy about it, but this language feature is there for a purpose, so when you can safely use it, USE IT. Do you have any other example, when it can break the build?

Answer (score 1):

If there could be more different structs implementing the protocol, use:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func a()
}

struct SomeStruct: SomeProtocol {
    func a() {
        print("a called from SomeStruct")
    }
}

let x = SomeStruct() as Any // Just as an example

if let x = x as? SomeProtocol {
    x.a()
}
```

Comment: I cannot cast it to `SomeStruct` as there may be more than this `struct` that implements the protocol and come in `arg`

Comment: I didn't cast it to struct.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a value of `Any` type, you can test for conformance and execute like so:

```
(arg as? SomeProtocol)?.someFunction()
```

Or, if you want it to have wider scope:

```
guard let conformer = arg as? SomeProtocol else { return }
conformer.someFunction()
```

Comment: `(arg as? SomeProtocol)?` fails - I want it to pass - because, it really implements `SomeProtocol`

Comment: If it fails, then no, it really doesn't implement `SomeProtocol`.

Comment: It sounds like you're mistaken about what is showing up in your argument, and the problem is actually elsewhere in your code.

Comment: If you have some time, we can Skype and I can show you the code.

Comment: I have edited question to add image showing the failure